# R: How to apply median to combn output?

Tags: r, vector, median, combn

I have a dataframe:

```
df1
vec1  vec2  vec3  vec4  vec5
0     10    5     12    5
10    20    13    1     7
20    30    28    13    16
```

And I perform combn() on it:

```
x = combn( df1[,1:4] , 3 )
```

Which returns a matrix like this:

```
x
V1           V2
c(0,10,20)   c(0,10,20)
c(10,20,30)  c(5,13,28)
c(5,13,28)   c(12,1,13)
```

And I want to obtain a vector where each element going down is the median value of each n in c(n,n+1,n+2) of each column of x. Like this:

```
y
V1                         V2
5 #(median of 0,10,5)      5 #(median of 0,5,12)
13 #(median of 10,20,13)   10 #(median of 0,5,12)
28 #(median of 20,30,28)   20 #(median of 20,28,13)
```

So you see it is transformed so that each item going down the vectors in y is the median of each n element in the original combn() vectors of lists.

Comment: `combn( df1[,1:4] , 3, median)`?

Comment: Error in median.default(x[a], ...) : need numeric data

Comment: It has to do with the fact that the elements of x are up a level

Comment: @RichardScriven I played around with that and it seems to work however the output is flipped on rows and columns

Comment: How about `t(apply(df1[1:4], 1, combn, 3, median))`

Comment: That is the answer my friend. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply()` to apply `combn()` over the rows, then use the `median()` function in `combn()`, transposing the result.

```
t(apply(df1[1:4], 1, combn, 3, median))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    5   10    5   10
# [2,]   13   10   10   13
# [3,]   28   20   20   28
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(vec1 = c(0L, 10L, 20L), vec2 = c(10L, 20L, 30L
), vec3 = c(5L, 13L, 28L), vec4 = c(12L, 1L, 13L), vec5 = c(5L, 
7L, 16L)), .Names = c("vec1", "vec2", "vec3", "vec4", "vec5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I give Richard's code the nod because it is about 3x faster than Frank's first answer, and I had some trouble implementing Frank's second code, namely, the result it gave was not a matrix but rather a vector. Thank you both.